# QTableview row metadata

Tags: qt, row, metadata, qtableview, user-roles

In a QTableView I'm trying to add some metadata for each row. An obvious solution would be to use the `Qt::UserRole` on the last column. Something like this.

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel();
QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem();
item->setData("Hello", Qt::DisplayRole);
item->setData(rowMetadata, Qt::UserRole);
model->setItem(ROW_0, COL_0, item);
// Getting the metadata as follows
model->data(model->index(ROW_0, COL_0), Qt::UserRole);
```

Something feels wrong though.
Any more intuitive solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to subclass `QAbstractItemModel` and build your own internal model and then you can store meta data any way you like. If `QStandardItemModel` otherwise works well for you, then this might be more work than just sticking with what you're already doing.

The other possibility I can think of is to use your existing `QStandardItemModel` and a `QSortFilterProxyModel`. In the base model, you can store your meta data as extra columns and then in the proxy, just make sure those columns are always hidden from the view.

Comment: Thanks! The second solution is what I have. But it's good to be aware of the "clean" way.